# How to process JS file returned from Express response.sendFile()

Tags: node.js, express, fetch

I have an API which uses Node.js + Express on the backend.

For one of the API endpoints, I'd like to use the Express response object method of "sendFile", documented here:

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile

The API should return a Javascript file through the sendFile method.

What I can't figure out is how to read in the .js file on the front end so that I can use the JavaScript functions defined in the file. The sendFile portion appears to be working -- it's just the use of the file which I can't figure out.

Here's what I'm doing on the backend:

```
app.get("/api/member", async (req, res) => {
  
  options = {
    root: path.join(__dirname, '/static'),
    dotfiles: 'deny'
  }

  res.sendFile("member.js", options, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent file')
    }
  })

});
```

This seems to be working fine, as I can navigate to the endpoint on my localhost and it loads the JS file. The file member.js simply contains some javascript function definitions.

But, I can't figure out how to consume/use the file once it arrives to the front end.

Here's what I have currently on the frontend:

```
async function refreshJS() {

  const url = `${baseUrl}/member`;
  const response = await fetch(url, { credentials: "include" });
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.type = "text/javascript"
  script.src = response.body
  document.head.appendChild(script)
  eval(script)
  
}
```

I've spent a lot of time looking through the console/debugger to find the text associated with the JS functions -- but they're nowhere to be found.

I've tested this general framework by loading JS files locally through the console and it worked, so I think it's wrapped up in a misunderstanding of where the JS functions live in the API response. For example, if I replace the command above of:

```
script.src = response.body
```

with

```
script.src = "member.js"
```

then everything works fine provided I have the file locally.

The examples that I've reviewed seem to deal exclusively with sending an HTML file which is loaded on the frontend. But, I can't find supporting documentation from the fetch API to understand how to use the JS file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Determined the answer to my own question. Here's the frontend code that made it work.

```
async function refreshJS() {
  const url = `${baseUrl}/member`;
  const response = await fetch(url, { credentials: "include" });
  eval(await response.text())
}
```